# Запись в переменную первого найденного имени папки

Tags: bash, shell

Есть архив `.tar.gz`, который выкачивается с помощью `wget`. В итоге я имею архив, лежащий в папке. После я распаковываю этот архив в другую папку с помощью команды

```
tar -xf myfile.tar.gz -C someDir
```

Я знаю, что в архиве будет лишь одна папка, но не знаю её имени, т.к. при упаковке имя может меняться (на номер версии, например).

**Вопрос:** Как мне записать в переменную имя этой распакованной папки, если я знаю, что имя её будет начинаться с `MyDistr_2000.3000.5000`, к примеру?

Получал имя папки в консоли таким образом:

```
ls -t someDir | head -1
```

С помощью какой команды можно записать имя папки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Получал имя папки в консоли таким образом

таким же образом и запишите в переменную:

```
переменная=$(ls -t someDir | head -1)
```

---

можно и без распаковки файлов:

```
переменная=$(tar -tf myfile.tar.gz | head -1)
```

Comment: Хм, видимо когда я пробовал `myDir=(ls someDir | grep MyDist)` у ничего не присваивалось (хотя и находило), со вторым вариантом я так не пробовал, но да, получилось спасибо. А распаковывать архив нужно) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: знак доллара пропустили: `myDir=$(ls ...`

Comment: Точно, в этом я прокололся. Спасибо